# How to optimize the code , while exporting to csv?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to export to a csv file based on certain rules. It will take more time while exporting to csv. Can anyone suggest how to optimize the code?

Code Snippet :

```
readCsv = pd.read_csv(inputFile)     

readCsv.head()     

readCsv.columns  

readCsv[(readCsv[attributeKey.title()].str.casefold()).str.contains(str.lower(Key))==True]
.to_excel(r"C:\\User\\Desktop\\resultSet.xlsx", index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you edit your question and format the last line, please? At the moment it is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 10000000)})

attributeKey = 'column1'
Key = 'abc' #the string you are checking for

start = time.time()
df[df[attributeKey.title()].str.lower().str.contains((Key).lower())]
end = time.time()

print(end - start)

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

**Edit1: Answer 2**

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 10000000)})

attributeKey = 'column1'
Key = 'abc' #the string you are checking for

start = time.time()
df[df[attributeKey.title()].str.lower().str.contains((Key).lower())]
end = time.time()

print(end - start)

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

10.000.000 rows takes `6.47` seconds. Anything bigger and I get a memory error. If you need bigger you might need to look into Dask.

**Edit2: Answer 3**

Changing to apply cuts time down by about half.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

def check_key(s):
    return KEY.lower() in s.lower()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 10000000)})

KEY = 'abc' #the string you are checking for
ATTRIBUTE_KEY = 'column1'

start = time.time()
df[df[ATTRIBUTE_KEY.title()].apply(check_key)]
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

Output: `3.3952105045318604` seconds

**Edit 3: Answer 4**

Just for fun, trying with multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import  Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def run_on_subset(func, data_subset):
    return data_subset.apply(func)

def parallelize_on_rows(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, func), num_of_processes)

def check_key(s):
    return KEY.lower() in s.lower()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 10000000)})

KEY = 'abc' #the string you are checking for
ATTRIBUTE_KEY = 'column1'

start = time.time()
parallelize_on_rows(df[ATTRIBUTE_KEY.title()], check_key)
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

Outputs `6.306780815124512`, so answer 3 seems to be the most efficient, with this size data anyway.

Comment: Yes , It works good for small datasets . For large dataset it will take more time , so how to optimize for that?

Comment: No problem @sharath. If you liked the answer, please take some time to accept it by ticking it, thanks :-)